# Maven assembly:single loses structure under Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a pom.xml profile set up that calls Maven (2.2.1) assembly to create a custom artifact that we'll upload to a third-party vulnerability assessment tool. The configuration is very straightforward - stripped to its essentials it's

```
<dependencySet>
   <includes>
      <include>${project.groupId}:*:jar</include>
   </include>
   <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
</dependencySet>

<dependencySet>
   <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
   <includes/>
   <excludes>
      <exclude>${project.groupId}:*</exclude>
   </excludes>
</dependencySet>
```

That is - the top level directory has our jars, stripped of version info, and all of the dependencies are in a /lib directory and include version info.

This is pretty straightforward and it works on my desktop.

On the Jenkins server everything is slammed into the top directory and version info is stripped.

My first thought was that there might be a problem with ${project.groupId} on the server. That seems unlikely but is an obvious thing to check. Unfortunately the problem remains.

It's not because it's tar.gz either - I see the same behavior with .zip?

Any ideas?

Comment: compare the versions of the assembly plugin that is used locally and on jenkins (use the -X parameter to see the debug output). You most likely have different versions of the plugin. Just make sure that they both use the same plugin version and you should be good to go.

Comment: To expand on peter's comment, add a pre-build step to print all environment variables. You may be surprised by all the environment variables jenkins sets that will clobber maven poms, especially resource filtering!

Comment: Thanks. We discovered this independently this morning. (Note to self: SO doesn't send mail on comments, only answers! Remember to check the site!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally tracked down the problem. The pom.xml file did not contain an explicit version for maven-assembly-plugin and I didn't notice it since everything worked.

Later, after we pushed to the build server, it failed. We verified that the maven versions matched but didn't think to check the plugin versions since all other dependencies require explicit version values. Once we did think to add the version (2.2-beta-4, to start) it worked.